# Install Shield Custom Action call dll from other dll

Tags: c#, dll, installshield

I am creating an installer and is using custom action writing code in c#.
In the method called by custom action is calling another common method which is in different class of different, so basically in different dll..

When am trying to run installer, it throws an exception saying :
System.FileNotFoundException : could not load file or assembly CustomAction.Logger

though the custom action am calling through install sheild is in different dll, 
so basically custom action is invoking the method perfectly, but when am calling the common method, it is throwing the error.

So, Can we get it done Anyhow?

Regards
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

**Valid for all MSI based installations.**

If the custom action you have is added as an attached file, then at install time Windows Installer extracts to TEMP directory, with a random generate name and runs it from there.

If you simply load the second DLL by its name, not full path, then this DLL must also be in the TEMP directory. Or of course specify the full path of the DLL.

Some installer authoring tools have support to for temporary files (i.e. to define a file you add in the project that is temporary so the installer extracts it from the beginning in the TEMP folder, and not after the *InstallFiles* standard action), I don't know if IS has one because I don't use it.